# How to add title to formattable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am making the following formattable. Since my data includes multiple groups (not included in the sample data), I will be subsetting my full data frame multiple times to create a table for each factor group in the `Group` column. I was wondering how I could add a title to the top of the table, so that I can see which subset the table is referring to. For these tables, I would like the title to simply be the value in the value in the `Group` column. So for the table below, the title would just be "1".

```
ex <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Var1 = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Var2 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

```
library(formattable)
formatex <- formattable(ex)
```

[image]

Comment: One question at a time: it's the SO way. See [ask]. Also no TIA messages. I'm guessing your really out to have an example with more than one group and some sort of subset operation.

Comment: The detail about subsetting is just to provide context and explain why I want the title to reflect the value in the group column. I do not need any guidance on how to subset data. The data provided is an accurate representation of what my data will look like after subsetting. So the question as written requests exactly what I need (and more than enough to answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this? The code below adds `Group 1` as title. If you want it to say just `1` then change the following `caption = <insert title>`.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(formattable)

ex <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Var1 = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Var2 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

formattable(ex) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F, caption = "Group 1", align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r"))
```

[image]

**OR**

Literally apply the first value in `Group` as title. In this case, the title would be `1` as you alluded to in the body of your question.

```r
formattable(ex) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F, caption = ex$Group[1], align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r"))
```

[image]

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

```r
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(formattable)
library(kableExtra)

ex <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Var1 = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Var2 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

formattable(ex) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F, caption = "Group 1", align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r")) %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, I'm very new to `knitr`-- when I try to replicate your code, I get this text as the result in my console: ```<table>
<caption>1</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> Group </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> Var1 </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> Var2 </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> 1 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> A </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> X </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>'''```
And so on. Am I missing something?

Comment: How exactly are you replicating the code? Clicking the Knit button in RStudio? Clicking the Run button on the code chunk? And session info (xfun::session_info('rmarkdown'))?

Comment: Just executing the code chunk in the script editor. I am not quite sure what you mean by output format--do you mean what kind of file format ie: png?

Comment: ```R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)


Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 digest_0.6.27   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.2      graphics_4.0.3 
  grDevices_4.0.3 highr_0.8       htmltools_0.5.0 jsonlite_1.7.1  knitr_1.31     
  magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1    methods_4.0.3   mime_0.9        rlang_0.4.8    
  rmarkdown_2.3   stats_4.0.3     stringi_1.4.6   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.24   
  tools_4.0.3     utils_4.0.3     xfun_0.22       yaml_2.2.1     

Pandoc version: 2.7.3
```

Comment: Try installing `library(kableExtra)` then pipe the result into the `kable_styling()` function.

Comment: I have added a troubleshooting section to the bottom of my solution. it should look like that on your machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229919/discussion-between-iamericfletcher-and-rogues77).

Comment: Using `kable_styling` fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

formattable(ex, caption = ex$Group[1])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This adds nothing not already covered by the existing, much older answer.

Comment: It does exactly what the OP wanted without adding kable, which is what all the other answers used. It simply adds a title to formattable using the group #.